# Register Api Controller is not saving the hashed password

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, registration, dto

Yesterday, my coworker accidently deleted the database. I deleted my old migration folder and re-migrated to the database using the same code. When I attempt to register a new dummy user, the Hashed password in the database is registered as null always. This is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("register")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status202Accepted)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] UserDTO userDTO)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Registration Attempt for {userDTO.Email} ");
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    try
    {
        var user = _mapper.Map<ApiUser>(userDTO);
        user.UserName = userDTO.Email;
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(error.Code, error.Description);
            }
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, userDTO.Roles);
        return Accepted();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, $"Something Went Wrong in the {nameof(Register)}");
        return Problem($"Something Went Wrong in the {nameof(Register)}", statusCode: 500);
    }
}
```

My User Model

```
public class ApiUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Finally My UserDTOs

```
public class LoginUserDTO
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Your Password is limited to {2} to {1} characters", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class UserDTO : LoginUserDTO
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Roles { get; set; }

}
```

So why is the hushedpassword always saved as null

Answer (score 0):

```
public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityResult> CreateAsync (TUser user, string password);
```

You could try calling this overload of the `CreateAsync` method, and see if it solves the problem. Also, check if the mapper maps correctly the DTO to the `ApiUser` object.

So from this: `var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);` you would get `var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userDTO.Password);`

Comment: Edited the post, added a more detailed explanation. Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. Please specify what else I should be adding for the problem to be clear